# Make a palette containing gxt widgets

Tags: gwt, gxt

I m working on a web gui editor.

I need to make a palette( treepanel containing a representation of all the gxt widgets)
I didn't find how to fill the palette with a representation of the widgets (a widget can be represented by a button and icon) and when dropped i get the widget itself.
Did the components have to implement BaseModel.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at [Sencha's example tree](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#overview) for guidance?